# Use JAX-RS GenericType for Jackson object mapping

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I want to write a proxy for `javax.ws.rs.client.SyncInvoker`:

```java
    @Override
    public <T> T get(GenericType<T> responseType) {
        String payload = delegate.get(String.class);
        // very important logic...
        return objectMapper.readValue(payload, responseType); // fix this
    }
```

Of course, the code above does not compile, because jackson doesn't know anything about `GenericType` from jax-rs. It seems that I could use one of these methods:

```java
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
public <T> T readValue(String content, JavaType valueType)
```

But I'm confused finding the right way to convert `GenericType` to `TypeReference` or`JavaType`.

Comment: What about `JavaType javaType = objectMapper.constructType(responseType.getType())`?

Comment: @jannis omg thank u so much. I've suffered all day, and the solution was so simple... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer. Try this:

```
JavaType javaType = objectMapper.constructType(responseType.getType())
```